sqlx left join and optional types
sqlx query_as macro seems to have an issue with left join and null values
The following query is used with query_as
select
    vehicles.*,
    vehicle_make.name as make_name,
    vehicle_model.name as model_name
from vehicles
left join vehicle_make on vehicles.make_id = vehicle_make.id
left join vehicle_model on vehicles.model_id = vehicle_model.id
where fleet_id = $3 order by license_plate limit $1 offset $2

In the SQL level make_name return as a varchar value or as null
The rust data struct contains a field pub make_name: Option<String> to hold that value.
Running that query results in
error occurred while decoding column 11: unexpected null; try decoding as an `Option`

The error comes from
    vehicle_make.name as make_name,
    vehicle_model.name as model_name

If I remove from the table all null values from vehicles.model_id or vehicles.make_id so the query successfully  retrieve values for make_name / model_name - The error does not occur.
Any suggestions on how to resolve the issue?

Looks like its possible to mitigate the issue using a ? operator, not standard PostgreSQL - but an sqlx feature. The following code works, perhaps there's a better solution for the issue, answer or comment if you find one.
query_as!(
          Vehicle,
          r#"
select
    vehicles.*,
    vehicle_make.name as "make_name?",
    vehicle_model.name as "model_name?"
from vehicles
left join vehicle_make on vehicles.make_id = vehicle_make.id
left join vehicle_model on vehicles.model_id = vehicle_model.id
where fleet_id = $3 order by license_plate limit $1 offset $2
          "#,

          items_per_page,
          offset,
          fleet_id
)



Holy smokes thank you, it took my ages to figure this out

#rustlife baby...
